# Page refresh (F5) in JQM native app clear's the dom -> no styles and scripts loaded

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have one larger .js file loaded in the head of the app. entry point (index.html) instead of loading page-specific scripts inside their data-role="page" div.

So i have all the page specific scripting in one js that is loaded once from the index.html which always remains in the DOM.

So for example i have handlers like:

$(document).on('pageshow', '#page_Albums', function()
{
   // code for the albums.html page 
});

..etc

This is my problem:

When you start navigating the app everything is okey until you hit f5 or browsers refresh button.

This so called full-refresh won't load my central js file, also the needed jquery-mobile resources from the head of index.html (js & css) are lost.

Due to this it's obvious where the problem lies. When i hit refresh from index.html then everything works fine.

How to fix this?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the navigation links try use `data-ajax="false"` it will re-command your js...

For example,

```
<a href="#xyz" data-ajax="false>Link</a>
```

Comment: thx but that doesn't help. My problem is not a result of a link clicked, but the result of the browser's refresh button clicked, when i'm in the middle of my app navigating somewhere. I also stated that it's likely due to the missing files that i include externally from the entry point (index.html) instead of doing per-page scripting - because i have a bigger website going on.